# Help me to draw the figure using tikzpgf plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

How to draw the following figure using Tikzpgf ?

[image]

I need to plot with **the axes exactly** in the figure. Also I want to display the vertex (4,-2).

I know to join two points (a,b) and (c,d) by straightline, we use the code

```
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\draw (a,b)--(c,d);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Here in the picture, we have to join

> (0,1) to (1,0), (1,0) to (2,-1), (2,-1) to (4,-2), (4,-2) to (8,-3)  and $(0, v_p(\alpha)$ to (1,0).

I **don't want axes** like given below

[image]

Please help me to plot the figure.

Also tell me which package should I add with my latex editor to draw pgf plot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With pure TikZ:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3.14159 mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
% axis
\draw[-Straight Barb] (-1,0) -- (9,0) node[right] {$n$};
\draw[-Straight Barb] (0,-3) -- (0,3) node[above] {$v_2(a_n)$};
% ticks and dashed lines, drawn in loop
\foreach \i [count=\j from 0] in {1,2,4,8}
    \draw[densely dashed] (\i,0) node [above] {\i} -- (\i,-\j) coordinate (x\j);
\foreach \i/\j/\k in {-1/-1/3, 0/0/2, 1/1/1, 2/$v_p(\alpha)$/0}
\path[draw=red, dashed] (0,\i) node[left,fill=white, inner sep=2pt] {\j} -- (x\k);
% function
\draw[thick, green]  plot coordinates {(0,2) (1,0) (2,-1)};
\draw[thick,   red]  plot coordinates {(2,-1) (4,-2)  (8,-3)};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Code you can compile in your local installation of LaTeX or using [Overleaf service](https://www.overleaf.com/).

**Edit:**

Above MWE works independent from the used `\documentclass`. For example, if you use the `amsart` package, than the firs code line

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3.14159 mm]{standalone}
```

replace with

```
\documentclass[12pt,leqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
```

Result is the very same as before, with no errors nor warning nor bad box messages.

In the case, that you like to include above diagram as figure with caption in your document, you can insert it in `figure` float environment and add caption as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,leqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{pgfplots}       % it also load tikz package
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}   
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,
            citecolor={black}]{hyperref}

\usepackage{lipsum} % added for generating a dummy text, 
                    % not needed in real document
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]  % dummy text
\begin{figure}[ht] % placed here or on the top of page
    \begin{tikzpicture}
% axis
\draw[-Straight Barb] (-1,0) -- (9,0) node[right] {$n$};
\draw[-Straight Barb] (0,-3) -- (0,3) node[above] {$v_2(a_n)$};
\foreach \i [count=\j from 0] in {1,2,4,8}
    \draw[densely dashed] (\i,0) node [above] {\i} -- (\i,-\j) coordinate (x\j);
\foreach \i/\j/\k in {-1/-1/3, 0/0/2, 1/1/1, 2/$v_p(\alpha)$/0}
\path[draw=red, dashed] (0,\i) node[left,fill=white, inner sep=2pt] {\j} -- (x\k);
% function
\draw[thick, green]  plot coordinates {(0,2) (1,0) (2,-1)};
\draw[thick,   red]  plot coordinates {(2,-1) (4,-2)  (8,-3)};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Caption of the figure} % caption
\label{fig:diagram}             % for referencing of figure, key select as you wish
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]  % dummy text

For further explanation see figure \ref{fig:diagram} \dots % referencing of figure
\end{document}
```

Which gives the following result (showed is a part of page):

[image]

As expected, the compilation of this MWE is also error-free.

Comment: Yes I have compiled it on my latex editor "Latex Studio", I have  am document class `\documentclass[12pt,leqno]{amsart}`. It is plotting nicely but showing error `Package pgf Error: Arrow end type ``Straight Barb'' unknown \draw[-Straight Barb]`. Please help

Comment: To me in OP,  the third leg appears orange, the forth black. ;)

Comment: Please see the latex package I use,in the following answer by `me`. Your code is perfect but not adjustable with the package I use.Please help

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR. see edit in my answer.

Comment: @Zarko, Thank you for continuous effort. But still the same problem. It says `i can't find file tikzlibraryarrows.meta.code.tex`. It says`i am going to ignore \pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}`. I think my latex is editor/package is old. Can you help how to update it ? I use`Tex studio` latex editor

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR, this error is caused by your LaTeX installation. If you have installed MikTeX, then go to *MikTeX Console* and in it press button *Upgrade*. I'm not familiar with TeXlive, so I can't give any advice for it.

Answer (score 4):

And with `tikz` and `pgfplots`:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\begin{axis}[mystyle/.style={semithick},
  axis x line=center,
  axis y line=center,
  xtick={0,1,2,4,8},
  ytick={-1,1},
  extra y ticks={3},
  extra y tick labels={$\nu_p(\alpha)$},
  xlabel={$n$},
  ylabel={$\nu_2(a_n)$},
  xlabel style={right},
  ylabel style={above},
  x tick label style={anchor=south,above,yshift=1ex},
  yticklabel style={red},
  extra y tick style={yticklabel style={color={black}}},
  xmin=-1,
  xmax=9,
  ymin=-4,
  ymax=4]
% Main lines
\addplot[mystyle,green,thick]coordinates{(0,3)(1,0)(2,-1)};
\addplot[mystyle,orange,thick]coordinates{(2,-1)(4,-2)};
\addplot[mystyle,thick]coordinates{(4,-2)(8,-3)};
% red dashed help lines
\addplot[mystyle,dashed,red]coordinates{(0,1)(1,0)};
\addplot[mystyle,dashed,red]coordinates{(0,0)(2,-1)};
\addplot[mystyle,dashed,red]coordinates{(0,-1)(4,-2)};
% vertical dashed lines
\addplot[mystyle,dashed]coordinates{(2,0)(2,-1)};
\addplot[mystyle,dashed]coordinates{(4,0)(4,-2)};
\addplot[mystyle,dashed]coordinates{(8,0)(8,-3)};
\node at (0,0) [above,anchor=south west,shift={(-0.075cm,0.075cm)}] {0};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The small problem is, I use `\documentclass[12pt,leqno]{amsart}` in my Latex editor.

Comment: How to add caption below the figure ?

Comment: Everything goes fine except 0 is placed below -1.  Please see the figure below in $my$ answer. I think the problem is in the last line of your code to adjust with my latex editor `\node at (0,0) [above,anchor=south west,shift={(-0.075cm,0.075cm)}] {0};`

Comment: This must have to do with your local setup. Please leave the node where it is in the axis environment. If you use a current version of pgfplots it should automatically use `axis cs` scope. But it appears to use the global coordinate system placing the node at the origin of the whole tikzpicture. I suggest to try to update your pgfplots / tikz to the newest version. Alternatively you can try `\node at (axis cs:0,0) [above,anchor=south west,shift={(-0.075cm,0.075cm)}] {0};` (untested).

Comment: Caption below the figure? You will find many examples online or on this platform.

Comment: Did you see my Latex package below in the answer by `myself`? Can you suggest to update by which new packages ?

Comment: Yes, thanks, `\node at (axis cs:0,0) [above,anchor=south west,shift={(-0.075cm,0.075cm)}] {0};` solved the problem.Now it is ok

Comment: You do not need any additional usepackages, you need `tikz` and `pgfplots`. But update those to the current version. You can put `\listfiles` in your preamble (where you load all the packages, before `\begin{document}`, then look at the logfile for the version of `pgfplots`. Compare with most current version here: https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots?lang=en (currently 1.17). I suspect you will find a lower version number. Not too problematic, but may cause confusion, like it did here.

Comment: Final request,  I will search to put caption below the figure. But how to display the vertices, say, `(4,-2)` ?

Comment: Try this under the other node: \node[below, anchor=north] at (axis cs:4,-2) {(4,-2)};

Comment: Sorry, but another question. Suppose I want to display `(a,b)` exactly at the position of `(4,-2)` instead of (4,-2). How to do that ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113892/discussion-between-matthias-arras-and-m-a-sarkar).